# Accessing xml file from different app android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to  create a application in that i need to access the xml file which is in  different application.I have tried using packagemanager but i am able to get the resource  Ids of the xml file. How can i get the access of the complete xml from my app?

Comment: why do you need to do this?. There might be much simple solution to your problem.

Comment: I am having a theme in one app and i need to retrieve the theme and set in a different app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple !

1) save theme file to the local path (in phone)

2) store that path where your theme file stored **( try to manage with xml because its light weight so will be lighter in mobiles)**

3) import that file from the location **(fetched from xml file)**

Enjoy *XMLing* and *Android* !